# Advanced use of googletest's parameterization

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have several questions about googletest framework and its usage:

> By `fixture` in the following questions I mean a class derived from `::testing::Test`

1. As far as I know, I can use `fixture` along with `parameterization feature` of gtests. Does this apply to **both** `value-parameterization` and `type-parameterization`?
2. There are cases when the fixture is irrelevant. Can I use `type-parameterization` with `value-parameterization` **without** `fixture`? How (example would be nice)?
3. *Pure interest*: Can I use `fixture` **together** with `type-` **and** `value-parameterization`? (I am quite sure this is a needless complexity)

Comment: So with _`fixture`_ you mean the derived `::testing::Test` class? Some links for the particular features would be helpful to give concise answers to your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you're right, `fixture` == derived from `::testing::Test`this is what I mean. I guess, what I ask are already the features of the gtest. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know, I can use fixture along with parameterization feature of gtests.
>   Does this apply to both value-parameterization and type-parameterization?

Yes, both [value-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#value-parameterized-tests)
and [typed tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#typed-tests)
or [type-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#type-parameterized-tests)
must be derived from a fixture class. The linked documentation provides examples.

> Can I use type-parameterization with value-parameterization without fixture

I presume you mean "type-parameterization OR value-parameterization". Anyway, you cannot
use either without a fixture class, as per the same documentation.

> Can I use fixture together with type- and value-parameterization?

Googletest does not expressly support type-and-value-parameterized tests,
but you can make a good approximation to it with type-parameterized tests,
as I illustrated in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22272614/1362568)