# Googletest: Value-Parametrized Typed Test

Tags: c++, googletest

Suppose I have an interface `iface` and a couple of its implementations `A` and `B`. Now, object of classes `A` and `B` are constructed by reading certain files `f1,f2,...,fm.` That is, there are `m` objects, and if you consider the 2 implementing classes `A` and `B`, there are `2m` objects overall.
Now, https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests is a good starting place for automating the step of feeding the filenames `f1,...,fm` to the constructors. One then simply uses `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(MyGroup, BarTest, testing::Values(<some-way-of-getting-filenames>))`.
On the other hand, there is a concept of Typed-Test: on is able to supply different implementations of an interface, like so

```
typedef Types<A,B> impls;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(MyName,    // Instance name
                              FooTest,             // Test case name
                              impls);  // Type list
```

Here, `FooTest` is defined as

```
template<class T>
class FooTest : public ::testing::Test {
//...
}
```

again according to the documentation/sample at https://github.com/abseil/googletest/blob/master/googletest/samples/sample6_unittest.cc,
whereas `BarTest` is defined as

```
class BarTest : public ::testing::Test, public ::testing::TestWithParam<const char*>
```

Now I can see that what I need is a combination of `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` and `INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P`, over a class `FooBarTest` that derives from `testing::Test, TestWithParam`, and also has a template parameter `T`. The question is, is this possible? Is there such a macros?

Comment: This post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507385/google-test-is-there-a-way-to-combine-a-test-which-is-both-type-parameterized-a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Test: Is there a way to combine a test which is both type parameterized and value parameterized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507385/google-test-is-there-a-way-to-combine-a-test-which-is-both-type-parameterized-a)